# How do I extract only some specific body texts from a public HTML page in PHP?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I want to extract only some specific body innertexts from a particular HTML page. By specific, I mean only the innertexts which are related to the title of the page.

The thing is that I am scraping data from a public website, and it's full of advertisements, signup forms, etc, which are unnecessary and irrelevant to the title of the page.

I was going through the internet and found out a library call `SimpleHTMLDOM`, so I implemented it into my project. This is how I am fetching the body texts from the website:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html("URL of the website here");

if($html){
    if($html->find('p')){
        foreach($html->find('p') as $element){
            echo $element->plaintext.'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

As I feared, it's fetching all the unnecessary texts too which are inside the `<p>` tag. So my question is how do I segregate among the unecessary texts (from ads, etc) and the main body texts? Or is there any other library which will help me in doing so? Please guide me.

**EDIT:** As of now I am trying to fetch the necessary body text (excluding ads,etc) from this url:

[click to view](https://bengalmirrorthinkpositive.com/2023/01/05/vande-bharat-train-%E0%A4%AA%E0%A4%B0-%E0%A4%AC%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B2-%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%82-%E0%A4%A8%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%80%E0%A4%82-%E0%A4%B9%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%86/)

Comment: Narrow down your selector if you don't want to fetch all the `p`'s

Comment: All the innertexts, both relevant and irrelevant are inside the `p` tags

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/docs/1.9/api/simple_html_dom/find/). The first parameter passed to `find` is a `CSS style selector`. Use that to narrow down your query e.g. `$html->find('.container article p');` I can't imagine you can't possibly find out a selector that doesn't target any (or not most of) the adds

Comment: All the ads as well as the relevant `p`s have different `id` or `class` or have nothing at all. How will I know which one is specifically an ad or not?

Comment: How are we supposed to know if you don't post any relevant HTML example(s) of what you want to target?

Comment: @DarkBee my bad, I have included the `url` of the page from which I am trying to scrape the data in the post

Comment: AFAIK: none of the adds are inside any `p.has-medium-font-size` but inside a `div.code-block p`

Comment: The `url` that is being used is a dynamic one, it can be any `url` that is given as input by the user. In that case, how do I know which `selector` to use?

Comment: Short answer: You don't

Comment: @DarkBee so there is no way to extract the relevant body text from a dynamic url given as input by the user?

Comment: If you don't know what `HTML` to expect, how could you possible extract the correct information? What if said URL doesn't even use `p`-tags to put the text in? What about tags like `h1`, `h2`, `ol`, `ul`, etc.

Comment: There must be a way. Is there any other library that I am unaware of, which will help me in doing so?

Comment: Please think about it... how would you be able to know what _specific_ text to extract if you don't _specify_ what text you want to get? It's like asking you to extract a _specific_ paragraph I want from any random book, without giving you any more info what to look for.